# Server redrict error

Tags: php, html, server

**index.php**

```
<?php

    require 'linessystem/connection.php';


    $msg = "";
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {

        if ($_SESSION['level']=='admin' or $_SESSION['level']=='user') {
    header("location:linessystem/administrative/index.php");
        }
        if ($_SESSION['level']=='agent' && !empty($_SESSION['lang'])) {  
            if ($_SESSION['lang']=='ar') {header("location:linessystem/agent/ar/index.php");}
            if ($_SESSION['lang']=='hr') {header("location:linessystem/agent/hr/index.php");}
            if ($_SESSION['lang']=='en') {header("location:linessystem/agent/en/index.php");}
        }

    }


    if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {

                                        $username = $_POST['username'];
                                        $password = $_POST['password'];

                                        $query="select * from  users where username='$username' AND password='$password'"; 

                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysql_error($conn));

                                        $login  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                           if($login>0){
                                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                                            $_SESSION['lang']=$row['language'];
                                            $_SESSION['agent_id']=$row['agent_id'];
                                            $_SESSION['level']=$row['level'];
                    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                            if ($_SESSION['level']=='admin' or $_SESSION['level']=='user') {
                                                header("location:linessystem/administrative/index.php");
                                            }
                                            if ($_SESSION['level']=='agent' && !empty($_SESSION['lang'])) {
                                                if ($_SESSION['lang']=='ar') {header("location:linessystem/agent/ar/index.php");}
                                                if ($_SESSION['lang']=='hr') {header("location:linessystem/agent/hr/index.php");}
                                                if ($_SESSION['lang']=='en') {header("location:linessystem/agent/en/index.php");}
                                            }

                                        }
                                            }else{$msg= ' <div align="center"  style="color:red;font-weight: bold;font-size:15px;"> wrong username or password </div><br>';

                                        }}
    ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login-style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     </head>
      <body>
      <div class="login-page">
     <div class="form" align="center"   >

      <form class="login-form" method="post" action="index.php" id="loginid" >
      <input type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="username" 
     autocomplete="off">
      <input type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="password" 
      autocomplete="off ">
        <p class="message"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
        <button>login</button>

       </form>


     </div>
       </div>


      </body>
      </html>
```

I have an error in the server code of above one. I bought adomain and hosting and wh web siter is run already in other server  but in this new hosting isnt run when it reserve the value but don't redirect me to the main page and the url of new hosting is http://www.quicklineltd.com.
where is the problem that I could not make it ?

User name is 2 and pass is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even make it into the if statement? Try an echo instead of header.

And did you use a session_start(); at the beginning of your php file?

Or did you include the file above inside another file wich already echo'd some output, because then header wont work either.

Or you should have to put a slash in front of the path, or even use a full url as in http://

Answer (score 0):

Please use `session_start();` at the beginning of the file. Without starting the session, the sessions used in the file will not work.